# os.Interrupt is not working. How can I stop the program with the signal?

Tags: go, sockets, signals, exit, goroutine

`    package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"

    ses "github.com/jame/SES-algorithm/SES"
    "github.com/jame/SES-algorithm/network"
)

func main() {
numberProcess := 3
c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

// Create a context to signal cancellation to the network goroutines
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i < numberProcess; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(instanceID int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        ses.InitLog(instanceID)
        network := network.NewNetwork(instanceID, numberProcess)
        defer network.SafetyClose()
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                network.SafetyClose()
                return
            default:
                network.StartSending()
                network.StartListening()
            }
        }
    }(i)
}
// Wait for a signal from the OS
<-c

// Send a quit signal to the network goroutines
cancel()

// Wait for all goroutines to finish
wg.Wait()

os.Exit(0)
}`
```

I have the code above. I want to exit the program when receive signal ctrl + c but when I run it, it didn't receive the signal to stop the program.
Try to press ctrl + c to exit the program but it didn't work.
I want to exit the program when press 'Ctrl + C'

Comment: My guess is that `network.StartListening()` is a blocking process, if that is the case then the surrounding `select` statement will not exit, and therefore neither will the `for` loop enter the next iteration to be able to execute `<-ctx.Done()`, and therefore the surrounding function never exits, the deferred `wg.Done()` is never executed, and `wg.Wait()` never returns.

Comment: And if `network.StartListening()` is not a blocking process (and neither is `network.StartSending()`), then you have a different problem, then the `for` loop would call those functions repeatedly with abandon, and that doesn't seem like something you intended the program to do.

Answer (score 0):

`network.StartListening()` is a blocking process, you can test the theory in a simpler code to see that the whole logic is working fine.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    numberProcess := 3
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    // Create a context to signal cancellation to the network goroutines
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < numberProcess; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(instanceID int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            instanceID = 1
            defer fmt.Println("defer 2")
            for {
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    fmt.Println("done.")
                    return
                default:
                    fmt.Println("instanceID: ", instanceID)
                    // return
                }
            }
        }(i)
    }

    // Send a quit signal to the network goroutines
    cancel()

    // Wait for all goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()
    // Wait for a signal from the OS
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    os.Exit(0)
}
```